# is it possible to install android studio in both windows and linux on the same machine

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, ubuntu-12.04, genymotion

I have android studio installed on my windows operating system 64 bit 4 gb Ram but now i want to work in linux(ubuntu 12.04)which is installed on the same windows 7 (no separate partition)where the android studio is installed so will it cause any harm to my windows operating system or any performance issues.Searched a lot about it on google but no clues.Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: Why would you want to run Android Studio in your Linux VM (I'm assuming you're using a VM)?

Comment: @Razgriz i am not using VM to run ubuntu its installed on windows but i read that android studio works better in linux so i want to install it in linux

Comment: @Razgriz why someone marked by question as negative?

Comment: How do you install an OS on top of another OS without using VM? Can you expound on how you did that? I really don't see why a contained copy of Android Studio can harm the Windows Environment it is installed in.

Comment: @Razgriz I did it by install ubuntu in dual mode http://www.howtogeek.com/128347/5-ways-to-try-out-and-install-ubuntu-on-your-computer/.    The question is since the ubuntu and android studio both are in C drive can it slow down my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Dual Boot then it shouldn't slow down your system at all. Although it won't make sense to have Android Studio installed in Windows when you have it at your Linux since you might get confused on which OS you saved which project. It won't slow down your system because your Windows OS only "sees" the HD Partition for Windows, the same is the case for your Linux Partition.

That being said, Linux can only see and touch the resources in the HD allotted for Linux. And since you won't be able to run the two OS at the same time, you won't have RAM problems (which is a problem with Virtual Machines).

Also, if I am not mistaken, when you dual boot, strictly speaking, you are partitioning your Hard Drive. When you go check Windows' Drive C, it's no longer 500GB (or whatever the total size of your HD is).

Comment: @ Razgriz basically i want to switch android development from windows to linux thats why installing android studio on linux so first of all i have to save my projects on windows and uninstall android studio on windows and then install android studio on linux i think thats the right method to do it. Thanks for your answer it really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more commonly done by placing the Linux system inside a virtual machine on the Windows system.

Many universities establish uniform Linux environments for their students this way.  If you conduct a search, you may find prefabricated examples of this publicly available.

As described, it does not sound like the Linux would boot. Some sort of storage separation is required to define the operating system.  If one is placed inside the other as described, it will simply be a directory held in local storage.  To use it as the operating system, the CPU will need to be able to find it at boot without the help of the other system, thus the multiple partitions.

Emulated systems, like Cygwin or MinGW, will work within the context of another operating system, but they are built for that purpose.  They are simulated systems with a common collection of typical commands.  That gives a similar programming experience, but it doesn't fulfill the definition of an operating system because it doesn't cover CPU activity.

Virtual machines will bridge this gap by taking emulators a step further.  They will simulate the CPU activity, frequently I/O controls (e.g. own MAC address for the VM under control of the VM).  Virtual machines won't need a sepatate partition.

If the two Android installs are separated by one being inside a VM and the other being on the main Windows:  there's no immediate reason why they would not work.  If you ran the Android emulators in both, it's obvious that the one in the VM would be slower.  It might be unbearably slow.  There may be some competition for I/O when you start hooking up phones to the hardware.  So, as a practical matter, it could get bogged down for developing simultaneously this way.  Meanwhile, if the IDE fits within the VM with Linux, it could run.

Comment: @ gladiola i installed my ubuntu in dual mode.  http://www.howtogeek.com/128347/5-ways-to-try-out-and-install-ubuntu-on-your-computer/  .The question is since the ubuntu and android studio both are in C drive can it slow down my computer?

Comment: If by dual you mean dual boot, then the partitioning was probably done by the installer.  The required separation is already in place.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve your problem in a single intel core i3 processor with ram size 4 gb and harddisk of 1 tb is that ,
1>> just duel boot system :- here in these step you must duel boot your system with linux and window both you can found easy tutorials for doing that thing . 
2>>install jdk on both of system 
3>>just set path for java in both of system in linux it is not required .
4>>Now you go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.and download latest version of stdio in both of partition .
5>>Now you can create android apps in both of system